# Tips for Upgrading Gmaps v2 to v3 more quickly

Tags: javascript, google-maps

After upgrade my complete code i had here the most currents tips to upgrade your code. 
Add other if you like.

Use : new `google.maps.` in place of `G`...

- `GLatLngBounds()` --> `google.maps.LatLngBounds()`
- `GlatLng` --> `google.maps.LatLng`
- `GPoint` --> `google.maps.Point`
- `Event.addListener` --> `google.maps.event.addListener`
- `map.getInfoWindow().getPoint` --> `google.maps.getPosition()`
- `markers[i].getPoint()` --> `markers[i].getPosition()`
- `closeInfoWindow()` --> `map.InforWindow.Close();`
- `map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds)` --> `map.fitBounds(bounds)`
- `markers[i].setImage` --> `.setIcon`
- `map.InfoWindow.close()` --> create a function to close
- find in maps for objects --> `$('#id')[0]` or `$('#id').get(0)` or `document.getElementbyId`

Happy coding.

Comment: map.InforWindow.Close() => map.InfoWindow.Close()

stack overflow won't let me edit as single character

Comment: I have the same problem with Ossi.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153051/convert-this-from-google-maps-api-v2-to-v3

How can we convert it?

Comment: GSize(x,y) should become: google.maps.Size(x, y)

GIcon creation should be refactored to use: google.maps.MarkerImage( url, size:Size, origin?:Point, anchor?:Point, scaledSize?:Size )

map.addControl calls should be refactored into: MapOptions properties as follows:

var mapOpts = {
    panControl:        true,   // First half of replacing GLargeMapControl
    zoomControl:       true,   // Other half of replacing GLargeMapControl
    scaleControl:      true,   // Replaces GScaleControl
    mapTypeControl:    true    // Replaces GMapTypeControl
};