# how can we convert GTileLayerOverlay with GTileLayer to Gmap v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
function createOverlay(){
    var cRight = new GCopyrightCollection('Rithy 2010');
    var newLayer = new GTileLayer(cRight,11,13);
    newLayer.getOpacity = function () {return 0.2};

    if (this.minZoom) {
    newLayer.minResolution = function(){return this.minZoom};
    }
    if (this.maxZoom) {
    newLayer.maxResolution = function(){return this.maxZoom};
    }

    var newOverlay = new GTileLayerOverlay(newLayer);
    return newOverlay;

}
```

My question is the similar to [Convert this from Google Maps API v2 to v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153051/convert-this-from-google-maps-api-v2-to-v3)

I have been stuck for few days.
Please help me!

Comment: Does this help: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3#overlays

Comment: Thank you Duncan, I have seen that page too.
Now I am trying to use Overlaying an image map type
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay
It's working, and now I'm trying to toggle visibility of the overlay.