# Gxml.parse google maps migrating from v2 to v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to move Google maps from v2 to v3 in one of the applications I am developing. I saw this link [Tips for Upgrading Gmaps v2 to v3 more quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901817/tips-for-upgrading-gmaps-v2-to-v3-more-quickly). I could however not find an alternative for GXml.parse method in v2 API.

I am using downloadUrl function provided by this script http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/xmlparsing/util.js.

```
    function renderMap(mapControlFile) {   
            if (!mapControlFile || !xmlPath) {
                downloadUrl(mapConfigFile, function(data,responseCode) {

                    try {errorTest = errorTest;}
                    catch(e) {errorTest = null;}
                    if (responseCode!=200 || errorTest=='yes') {
                        document.getElementById('mapCanvas').innerHTML = mapDataError; 
                        document.getElementById('mapCanvas').innerHTML += '<p>Response Code: '+responseCode+'</p>'; 
                        return;
                    }
// The below line uses GXml which is now deprecated in v3
                    xmlDocument = GXml.parse(data);
                    //process config element -- restricted to 1 config element in the xml file
                    configElement = xmlDocument.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("config");
                    //check for xml file parsing errors
                    if (configElement.length==0) {
                        document.getElementById('mapCanvas').innerHTML = mapDataError; //<div> tag in html document
                        return;
                    }
                    //try-catch handler for potential undeclared variable "auth" across all browsers (controls access during maintenance)
                    try {auth = auth;}
                    catch(e) {auth = null;}
                    //try-catch handler for potential undeclared variable "maintenanceTest" across all browsers (used for maintenance message testing)
                    try {maintenanceTest = maintenanceTest;}
                    catch(e) {maintenanceTest = null;}
                    //check if campus map system is offline for maintenance
                    if ((GXml.value(configElement[0].getElementsByTagName("offline")[0]) && auth==null) || maintenanceTest=='yes') {
                        document.getElementById('mapCanvas').innerHTML = GXml.value(configElement[0].getElementsByTagName("offlineMsg")[0]); //<div> tag in html document
                        return;
                    }
                    //initialize and load default map
                    xmlPath = GXml.value(configElement[0].getElementsByTagName("xmlPath")[0]);
                    overlayURL = GXml.value(configElement[0].getElementsByTagName("overlayURL")[0]); //set global variable
                    //create map and add controls (documentation at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/)
                    //map canvas is styled in ../css/campusmaps.css
                    //Google Maps API Version 2
                    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("mapCanvas")); //<div> tag in html document
                    eval('map.setMapType('+GXml.value(configElement[0].getElementsByTagName("mapType")[0])+')');
                    map.addControl(new GSmallZoomControl3D());
                    zoomLevelMessage = GXml.value(configElement[0].getElementsByTagName("zoomLevelMessage")[0]); //set global variable
                    parseXml(xmlPath+GXml.value(configElement[0].getElementsByTagName("defaultMap")[0])); //function call to parse xml default map control file
                }); //end downloadUrl()
            } //end initialize and load default map
            else {
                parseXml(xmlPath+mapControlFile); //function call to parse xml map control files
            } //end load all non-default maps

    } //end renderMap()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options.

1. use the a third party library like jquery.
2. use [GXml.js](http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/GXml.js)
3. write an xml parsing routine like in my version of [downloadxml.js](http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/downloadxml.js)

Option 2:

```
function parse(textDoc){
   try{
      if(typeof ActiveXObject!="undefined"&&typeof GetObject!="undefined"){
         var b=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
         b.loadXML(textDoc);
         return b;
      }else if(typeof DOMParser!="undefined"){
         return(new DOMParser()).parseFromString(textDoc,"text/xml");
      }else{
         return Wb(textDoc);
      }
   }
   catch(c){
      P.incompatible("xmlparse");
   }
   try{
      return Wb(textDoc);
   }
   catch(c){
      P.incompatible("xmlparse");
      return document.createElement("div");
   }
}
```

Option 3:

```
function xmlParse(str) {
  if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined' && typeof GetObject != 'undefined') {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  }

  if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }

  return createElement('div', null);
}
```